# In Ruby (or Rails), is it faster to compare two large Strings as is, or convert it into Fixnum before using uniq?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Given 2000 `Story` objects, each with a `body` attribute that equates to a string of about 500 characters.

What is the fastest way to compare them?

1. Doing it like this: `@stories.uniq { |story| story.body }`

OR

2. First converting each `body` into a `Fixnum` representation, then running `uniq`?

I have vague feeling that computers are able to compare numbers faster than characters, but I also know that each character is really just represented in bytes.

Comment: What about using `.distinct` to let the database do the comparison? Pulling out all those records is going to be the slowest part anyways.

Comment: @max In my app, the `Story` objects are not `Active Record` objects. Just plain old Ruby classes.

Comment: Since there's only 2k of them, why don't you do some benchmarks and see for yourself? How you plan on "converting each `body` into a `Fixnum` representation" will probably be important with only 2k values as will the `body` values.

Comment: @muistooshort I agree...I was looking at some built in method that converts `body` into a `Fixnum` representation. I think anything I write will be slower than just comparing the `body` with `String` representation... Thanks.

Comment: to turn a string into an accurate integer you could use `"string".hash`, I have no idea of the performance; this would be a good use-case for benchmarks, though.

Comment: Your question has the terrible smell of premature optimization. Implement it the simple way. Determine where bottlenecks are. There's an nearly 100% chance this won't be it.

Comment: As a Stackoverflow matter, your question is too much about your own situation to be answered. (eg. we don't know about your exact case) Maybe try to phrase it so it can be useful for the community and so it can be answered.

Comment: @JonathanAllard I disagree. I came up with the `Story` example to make it easier to comprehend. In fact, if you just change the class name of `Story` to anything that has a text body, such as `Post`, `Comment`, or even `Poem`, the example will still stand. I don't see how using the word `Story` as a case is too much about my own situation, as the title of the post doesn't refer to it at all. In fact, my own situation is about finding unique job posts amongst 3 different APIs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's easy to benchmark things like these. For example:

```
require 'benchmark'

string_array = 1.upto(2000).inject([]) do |arr| 
  arr << 1.upto(500).inject("") { |str| str << rand(10).to_s } 
end

fixnum_array = string_array.map(&:to_i)

Benchmark.bm do |x|
  x.report("bignum:") { 1000.times { fixnum_array.uniq } }
  x.report("bignum_and_to_i:") { 1000.times { string_array.map(&:to_i).uniq } }
  x.report("string:") { 1000.times { string_array.uniq } }
end
```

Outputs:

```
                        user     system      total        real
bignum:             1.710000   0.010000   1.720000 (  1.729463)
bignum_and_to_i:   28.500000   0.160000  28.660000 ( 28.738891)
string:             1.740000   0.000000   1.740000 (  1.754165)
```

Comparing 2000 strings containing numbers of about 500 digits is very much faster than first converting the strings into numbers and then comparing.

Comparing long strings versus comparing large numbers won't make a big difference.

Conclusion: Converting long strings into large numbers is so slow that it's faster to just compare the strings.

Comment: Thanks for bringing up benchmarking ;) however, I feel like you should take the conversion of strings OP was suggesting into account. I think that will have a huge performance impact.

Comment: I updated the benchmarks to include the time it takes to run to_i.

Comment: @KimmoLehto Good stuff. My original intention wasn't to use `to_i`, but to use some cipher to convert text into unique strings. I figured out it would be faster to just run `uniq` on the string, rather than using a cipher to numerize it. I just thought, intuitively, that computers would be able to compare numerals faster than characters.